# Rewrite PostgreSQL query to clickhouse

Tags: sql, postgresql, clickhouse

I have a Postgres query:

```
SELECT 1 FROM vc_money_log_aggregated vmla2
                    LEFT JOIN vc_user_visits vuv2 ON vuv2.id = vmla2.visit_id
                    WHERE vmla2.uid = vu.id
                      AND coalesce(vuv2.app_type, (SELECT vuv2.app_type
                                                    FROM vc_user_visits vuv2
                                                        WHERE vuv2.uid = vmla2.uid
                                                        AND vuv2.dt < vmla2.from_dt
                                                    ORDER BY vuv2.dt DESC
                                                    LIMIT 1)
                                    ) NOT IN ('android', 'ios', 'wp')
                      AND vmla2.from_dt BETWEEN (SELECT start_dt FROM settings) AND (SELECT end_dt FROM settings)
```

I need to convert it to clickhose query. But how can i rewrite correlation query (coalesce section)? I tried to write this clickhouse query but i have out of memory exception:

```
select
    uid,
    app_type,
    dt
from
(select
   uid,
   max(dt) dt
from
(select
    uid,
    from_dt
from
    postgres_replica.vc_money_log_aggregated) t1
join
(
select
    app_type,
    dt,
    uid
from
    postgres_replica.vc_user_visits
) t2
USING uid
where t1.from_dt > t2.dt
group by
   uid) t3
join
(
select
    app_type,
    dt,
    uid
from
    postgres_replica.vc_user_visits
) t4
USING uid, dt
```

How should i rewrite this query?

Comment: `vmla2.uid = vu.id` <<-- there is no table-alias named `vu`

Comment: "vu" is the outer table. I think it is not important in this case. The problem is the correlation query:

SELECT vuv2.app_type
                     FROM vc_user_visits vuv2
                     WHERE vuv2.uid = vmla2.uid
                     AND vuv2.dt < vmla2.from_dt
                     ORDER BY vuv2.dt DESC
                     LIMIT 1